# How can I know screen density (like ldpi, mdpi, etc.) of following devices

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am making layouts for different screen density in android studio. But I don't know which device should I select in android studio for making ldpi layouts, then which device should I select for making mdpi layouts and so on. Is there any way to calculate screen density of below devices or can you tell it?

[Devices available in android studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdJna.png)

[Layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9HYV.jpg)

[Layout I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fQRc.jpg)

[All devices list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XKFV.png)

[New hardware as vivo y20g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVEds.png)

Thanks

Comment: Have you fixed the margins of the layout for the `first name` and `last name` ?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down in that same window you put a picture of, to "Generic Phones and Tablets". They're all called out for you:

[image]

If you need other densities, see [the documentation for what each [?]dpi value means](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) and create your own device that matches. A higher density just means you have more pixels per inch of screen. So create a device with a relatively high resolution and relatively low size screen.

[image]

Comment: But it don't have xxxhdpi option, is there any way I can calculate screen density from screen resolution or its dpi?

Comment: See update I posted.

Comment: I tried creating new hardware profile but I am getting different results (In android studio its showing different layout and in actual mobile its showing different layout), my mobile resolution are 720 * 1600 and screen size 6.51 inch, (Mobile model : vivo y20g), see my updated question

Comment: In your screenshot you have "Pixel" selected - after you creates a custom AVD, select it from the dropdown as I showed.

Comment: I created new hardware but it's not visible in that list, See screenshots in my question

Comment: Try restarting Android studio to refresh that list.